# What is this white stuff on my lime tree and should I be concerned?

Tags: diagnosis, citrus

My otherwise healthy lime tree (5 years old), has an odd white growth over it's surface. The ants seem to enjoy it.

Is this something that needs to be treated immediately or can I do it in the spring when I return?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am curious to see the answer on this, but that almost has to be ants farming aphids doesn't it?  or maybe ants eating honeydew from scales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like mealybug or scale, maybe whitefly, particularly as the ants are 'farming' for the honeydew. You need to treat it, I can see white flecks on the tops of other leaves, or at least, that's what it looks like in the second picture. Neem or Pest Oil should help, ensure you spray the underside as well as the tops of the leaves, and spray till run off.